# If there is a subset with sum divisible by n, then take out an integer of the subset. How many moves?

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

Fix an integer $n \ge 2$. A finite set $A \subset \mathbb{N} $ is given. 
Define $ s(X) = \sum_X x $, where $ X $ is a finite set. We know that $n \mid s(A)$.

We can do just one move: if there is a subset $S \subseteq A$ such that $n \mid s(S)$, then we can take out an arbitrary element of $S$. *To reduce* $A$ means to make a sequence of moves such that no more moves are possible. 
 
We call reduction degree of $A$ with respect to $n$ the minimum $d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that exists a sequence of $d$ moves which reduces $A$.

Is there a human way to explicitly find the degree of reduction of a set?
This is deeply linked with a problem of number theory I'm approaching with a friend of mine. 
Clearly, partial solutions of subcases would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I follow what you're getting at, but a specific example of such a 'game' would be clarifying.

Comment: For instance, take $ n=7 $ and $ A = \{1, \ldots, 6\} $. <br/>
Then $ d=3 $ , because: <br/>
1. You have to take out at least 1 number from each of the pairs $ (1,6),\ (2,5), \ (3,4) $ that sum to $0 \pmod{7}$. So $d \ge 3$. <br/>
2. Take sets $S_1 = (1,6), S_2 = (2,5), S_3 = (3,4) $ and apply the move taking out the greatest element. You are left with $ A' = \{1,2,3\}$ which is reduced. So $d \le 3$.